# Django runserver doesn't respond on browser despite port on 'LISTEN'

Tags: python, django, port, listen

I have stumbled on this issue that I have no clue how to resolve. When I run `python manage.py runserver` I get this:

[image]

I open http://127.0.0.1:8000/ (before quitting the server with CONTROL-C) on my browser, which shows the following result:

[image]

I tried all the solutions proposed on StackOverflow for similar problems.

I tried running python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 but it didn't change anything.

I checked my port was listening using `sudo nmap -sT -O localhost` and the result was this:

[image]

but when running `netstat -anv`, I get this:

[image]

I even tried killing it using `sudo lsof -t -i tcp:80` then `kill -9 xxxx` (with xxx being the pid).

All my proxies are deactivated (see below) so I have no clue what's going.

[image]

I have been trying to resolve this issue for the past two days. I am a beginner in Django and would like to know what is going on. I have been reading all threads on the website but haven't found a solution that suits me.

It was working perfectly the last time I worked on the project, and when I reopened it a couple of days later, the browser stopped working.

I am looking forward to your answer. Thank you!!

Comment: Just to be sure, the machine where you run `runserver` and the machine where you open the browser are the same machine, right? Can you post the output of `runserver`?

Comment: I just edited my original post @FamousJameous

Comment: Do you have a urls entry for `/`?

Comment: Edit the contents of your site and app `urls.py` files into your question if you are unsure.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. @FamousJameous I have urls entry in my site:

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

Comment: If those are the only entries in your `urls.py` file, then the 404 error makes sense - there's a route for `polls/` and a route for `admin/`, but no route for `/`. Try going to `127.0.0.1:8000/admin` and see if you're still getting a 404.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50425492/django-2-0-tutorial-pt-1-error-404-url-conf-probelm

Comment: add all your urls.py from project

Comment: I get it now but Im not sure how to fix it yet. How do I write a route for `/`? Is it `path('/')` in polls/urls.py?